# Colouring Symbols

Tags: symbols, color

I have a lot of data points that have been plotted in graphs. I need to make a table of those points with symbol as one of the columns. I need to have a red dot inscribed in a blue circle. This has to be in the column. 
"I also need a red dot inscribed in a blue circle which is inscribed in a triangle."
How do I go about doing this?

Comment: @ Christian Hupfer I don't need to plot them. I have already plotted them and saved as .png I need to mention the symbols that I have used in the table for ease of understanding the graph.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I think `tikZ` is what you need then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? Use `\bluereddot[...]` with a scaling factor or change the default factor `0.3` in the command definition.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\bluereddot}[1][0.3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1]
    \draw[fill=red,red] (0,0) circle (0.15);
    \draw[blue] (0,0) circle (0.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{document}

\bluereddot[0.1]
\bluereddot
\bluereddot[0.5]

\bluereddot[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted but how do I use this in a table?

Comment: @Bryan: The same way... just enter the command `\bluereddot` in the table cell you want to appear it...

Comment: Could you please help out. The statement within quotes.